# OData : filters with select provide inconsistent results

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have following structure.

```
Product
{
    GUID ID
    string Name
    GUID Category
    decimal Cost
    bool IsActive
}
```

In my configuration I have registered ID as a primary key.
I am trying to create a simple Get endpoint that retrieves all the data from Products.
The endpoint in itself works as expected in most cases.

---

- Works - /Products
- Works - /Products/?$filter=IsActive eq true
- Works - /Products/?$filter=ID eq {some guid}

---

While above is a fairly straight forward and works as expected, when i try to mix filters with select it seems to provide inconsistent results.

- Valid Results - /Products/?$filter=IsActive eq true and ID eq {some
  guid}&$select=Name,IsActive
- **Empty Results** - /Products/?$filter=IsActive eq true and ID eq {some
  guid}&$select=Name
- **Empty Results** - /Products/?$filter=ID eq {some guid} and IsActive eq
  true&$select=Name

---

- Valid Results - /Products/?$filter=IsActive eq true&$select=Name,IsActive
- **Empty Results** - /Products/?$filter=IsActive eq true&$select=Name
- **Empty Results** - /Products/?$filter=IsActive eq true and Cost ne null&$select=IsActive

---

In Case of 'or' I have found below results. Please note none of the values are null in my test data set.

- Valid Results - /Products/?$filter=Category ne null or Name eq 'Test Product'&$select=Cost,Name
- Valid Results - /Products/?$filter=Category eq null or Name eq 'Test Product'&$select=Cost (I had removed category from some of the data)
- **Empty Results** - /Products/?$filter=Category ne null or Name ne 'Test Product'&$select=Cost,Name
- **Empty Results** - /Products/?$filter=Category ne null or Name eq 'Test Product'&$select=Cost

---

Please note, I have written my own SQL and I have already verified that this generates proper dataset as expected, but oData seems to be doing some processing on the response object.
When I say doesn't work, I mean it just returns me an empty collection instead of giving me relevant values.

For my setup I am using oData V4 with all the latest dependencies.

Microsoft.ASPNet.OData - 6.1.0

Microsoft.Data.Edm/Core/Spatial - 7.4.3

Can someone please explain why the filter above behaves in such different ways?

**Additional Details**

When I looked at my response object that I return, it contains 20 odd elements.

```
OK(response)
```

I have created an attribute that overrides OnActionExecuted where context.Response.Content is null, instead of containing those 20 elements.

**Metadata**

```
<EntityType Name="Products">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
    <Property Name="IsActive" Type="Edm.Boolean" />
    <Property Name="Category" Type="Edm.Guid" />
    <Property Name="Cost" Type="Edm.Decimal" />
</EntityType>
```

Comment: For guid, this may help https://github.com/devnixs/ODataAngularResources/issues/10

Comment: problem is not about parsing guids in filters as only guid in filter works fine. It is about combining the filter and select statements. As I mentioned in all of the above queries data retrieved from SQL is correct.It is the post processing of oData that seems to be doing the filtering.

Comment: It seems that the problem scenario is at least one of the filter column must be in select. But that seems weird restriction to have?

Comment: Not necessary one of the filter column must be in select. OData is case sensetive for property names. Check that `Name` property exist not `name`

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to respond. It is not case sensitivity issue either as without select clause or with having same property in select, it provides correct result. Please check edit for the updates to the queries that may make it a bit clearer what works and what doesn't.

Comment: It's strange for not working. Can you post the metadata xml of the OData service?

Comment: Yes it is strange indeed. I couldn't find any such issue online or on odata test service endpoints, but I could also see the data being retrieved which means oData must be doing something. I have had strangest behaviour with 'ne' operator specially when compared with null (either as comparison value or actual data)

Comment: I guess,  try to use Microsoft.OData.Edm (>= 6.15.0 && < 7.0.0). Do you use Restier https://github.com/OData/RESTier to build OData.